# what if one of the object is deleted in C++?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

I saw the following code somewhere:

```
class Person {
   private:
       string *customerName;
   public:
        Person() {customerName = new string;}
        void setCustomerName(char *s) {*customerName = s;}
};


int main()
{
   Person person1;
   Person person2;

   person1.setCustomerName("Malcolm");
   person2 = person1;
}
```

are person1 and person2 all point to the same memory? and if person1 is deleted, or person2 is deleted, what will happen? does it will cause the corrupt the other object? or a memory leak?

Comment: Memory leak because your destructor doesnt delete the string.

Comment: This is poor code in many ways.  The string member should not be a pointer for starters (or there should be a copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor).

Comment: You just leak, that's all. It would result in double deletion if you had a destructor in `Person` that would do `delete customerName;`. Don't allocate the string dynamically and you'll be fine.

Comment: Is `string` a typedef of `char*`? If no, why do you think `char*` and `string` are same? If you don't think so, what do you think then?

Comment: Also, of course, _if_ you want to accept a `char*` in `setCustomerName`, it should be a `char const*`, since you don't modify anything in it.  (Luckily, in fact, since attempting to modify a string literal is undefined behavior.)

Comment: And of course, it should be `std::string customerName;`, without the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

> `person1` and `person2` all point to the same memory?

Their `customerName` pointers do point to the same memory, but the objects themselves are separate (albeit thay have an identical content).

> and if `person1` is deleted, or `person2` is deleted, what will happen?

Neither one can be deleted, but they can go out of scope. Nothing would happen, because there is no destructor (which is bad).

> does it will cause the corrupt the other object? or a memory leak?

An object of type `Person` going out of scope or being deleted would cause a memory leak even without an assignment. That is the fault of the `Person` class, because it does not have a destructor.

Every time you have an allocation in the constructor, you need a destructor to re-allocate the resources the constructor allocates. Once you add a destructor, [*The Rule of Three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) becomes relevant: you need to implement all of the following:

- A destructor,
- A Copy Constructor, and
- An assignment operator.

With all three functions implemented, your `Person` class becomes safe and leak-free: assignment of `person1` to `person2` cleans up the current `customerName` before making an assignment, and copies the string. Now two objects point to separate `customerName`s, ensuring that these could be destroyed without bringing each other down.

Note: Every time you see an explicit allocation in the constructor, ask yourself if that allocation is absolutely necessary, and that the pointer cannot be replaced with an object.

In case of your `Person` class the answer to "is the pointer necessary?" question is a resounding "no": you can easily make `string *customerName;` a `string customerName;`, which would immediately free you from the need to add a destructor, a copy constructor, or an assignment operator. Everything would "just work" - without memory leaks, double-deletes, or any other undesirable side effects.

Comment: person2 = person1; copy constructor is called? is this the reason why the customerName pointer to the same memory? but if through, if we delete person1, then person1.customerName is pointer to somewhere, which is cause undefined behavior?

Comment: @user2131316 "person2 = person1; copy constructor is called?" No, in this case the assignment operator is called. If you combine the assignment and the declaration, then the compiler would use the copy constructor. The default assignment operator copies the content of the memory, including the pointer, making both customerName pointers point to the same string. Currently, you cannot delete person1, because you did not call `new` for it; only pointers can be deleted.

Comment: while I do not understand why person2 = person1; did not call the copy constructor

Comment: @user2131316 Because it's not construction, but assignment.  `person2` has already been constructed.

Comment: @user2131316 This would call a copy constructor: `Person person2(person1);`

Comment: Of course, the way to fix this class is *not* to add destructors and things, but to remove the gratuitous dynamic allocation and just store a `string` value. The "Rule of Zero", if you will.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Absolutely - I added a note to discuss this. Thank you very much!